# How to generate a xlsx file with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file, xlsx

I can't find a way cross browsers to achieve this by pure javascript,is it better to give the job to backend developer to do?

Comment: Both are valid options. You'll have to detail your question a bit more to get a proper answer. I don't see any cross-browser issues here.